# Replace javascript array with item inside of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to show some data depending on which month it is. I have an array from 0 to 11. I'm confused on how to do this because there are multiple arrays inside of the object and it's scaring me lol

```
[
  {
    l: false,
    u: 'AU',
    n: 'Adelaide',
    rain: [
      22.4091,
      18,
      26.0909,
      42.875,
      56.9205,
      68.0568,
      75.4205,
      66.3636,
      58.8977,
      48.75,
      28.2159,
      27.9545,
    ],
  },
  {
    l: false,
    u: 'AU',
    n: 'A Different Place',
    rain: [
      22.4091,
      18,
      26.0909,
      42.875,
      56.9205,
      68.0568,
      75.4205,
      66.3636,
      58.8977,
      48.75,
      28.2159,
      27.9545,
    ],
  },
];
```

I have a variable that I can reference like this: getMonth(new Date(this.props.startDate))

`0`

Can I do something like this?

`forEach(data[x].rain[getMonth(new Date(this.props.startDate))])`

I'd like to replace the existing rain array with the data of the corresponding month. So for example if it was January (0) I'd like data[1].rain = 22.4091

expected output if (getMonth = 0):

```
[
  {
    l: false,
    u: 'AU',
    n: 'Adelaide',
    rain: 22.4091
  },
  {
    l: false,
    u: 'AU',
    n: 'A Different Place',
    rain: 22.4091
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: What do you want the output to be? It's confusing at the moment

Comment: to replace the array with the integer which is an index of month

Comment: if value will change based on month, you can't put 0, see below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()`. Return an object from `map()` with all properties same as previous but change `rain` to the the first element of it.

```js
 let arr = [ { l: false, u: 'AU', n: 'Adelaide', rain: [ 22.4091, 18, 26.0909, 42.875, 56.9205, 68.0568, 75.4205, 66.3636, 58.8977, 48.75, 28.2159, 27.9545, ], }, { l: false, u: 'AU', n: 'A Different Place', rain: [ 22.4091, 18, 26.0909, 42.875, 56.9205, 68.0568, 75.4205, 66.3636, 58.8977, 48.75, 28.2159, 27.9545, ], }, ];

const res = arr.map(x => ({...x,rain:x.rain[0]}))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: so I just put `[getMonth(new Date(this.props.startDate))]` instead of [0]?

Comment: @jaksco Yes try that and tell me if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
let data = [ { l: false, u: 'AU', n: 'Adelaide', rain: [ 22.4091, 18, 26.0909, 42.875, 56.9205, 68.0568, 75.4205, 66.3636, 58.8977, 48.75, 28.2159, 27.9545, ], }, { l: false, u: 'AU', n: 'A Different Place', rain: [ 22.4091, 18, 26.0909, 42.875, 56.9205, 68.0568, 75.4205, 66.3636, 58.8977, 48.75, 28.2159, 27.9545, ], }, ];

const res = data.map(x => ({...x,rain:x.rain[ (new Date(this.props.startDate).getMonth()) ]}))
console.log(res)
```

if this is already date then this.props.startDate.getMonth() else convert as above

Comment: cool. is there a difference in memory between .getMonth() and the way I was doing it? yours is working. I guess that means I don't need to import getMonth?

Comment: getMonth is default function of date in javascript, no need any imports